# Unity Invalid Operation Exception: System.Collects.Stack.Peek() - Operation invalid due to current state?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

So, I go to run the build in unity and I get this!

> InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current
>   state of the object System.Collections.Stack.Peek () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Stack.cs:321)
>   UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:280)
>   UnityEngine.GUILayout.EndScrollView (Boolean handleScrollWheel) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:427)
>   UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs:7090)
>   UnityEditor.ListViewShared+ListViewElementsEnumerator.MoveNext () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ListViewShared.cs:654)
>   UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow.OnGUI () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/ConsoleWindow.cs:409)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]

I've never seen such an exception before and so I figured I'd ask about it and then investigate.

Comment: are you trying to peek while another thread is in a foreach loop?

Comment: I'm hopefully going to chalk this up to anomalous due to unity's uncoolness with building while starting a scene. @Gusman

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke `Peek` or `Pop` on an empty `Stack<T>`.

```
Stack<GameObject> stack = new Stack<GameObject> ();
if (stack.Count > 0) {
    var top = stack.Peek ();
}
```